# Sort custom fields in admin by last field added

Tags: custom-field, wp-admin, sort

I'm trying to sort custom fields in admin post by last added fields but it sorted by words and number

example

my add is

```
3 , 6 , 4 , 7 , 5 , 1
```

when admin post save my custom sorted by number be like this

```
1 ,3,4,5,6,7
```

I need to change this sorting. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you want? More specifically where you want this functionality?

Comment: im so sorry i know my english is too bad .              custom fields in post admin sorting by number and words i need to change this sorting and make it sorted by last custom fields added example my added custom fields name is : 60,40,70. when i save the post custom fields display like this 40 ,60,70 sorting by number and i want to display it like i added it 40,60,70 .thank u

Comment: Where in the admin?

Comment: add new post page